# How to test if there is a significant difference in the proportion of 3 groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova

There are 3 hotels. In each, customers were asked if they would return for a second stay:
[image]

How could I test (alpha = 0.05) if there is a significant difference between the **proportion** of customers that would return for each hotel?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [chi square test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test). See [this link](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/BS704_HypothesisTesting-ChiSquare/BS704_HypothesisTesting-ChiSquare3.html) for a very intuitive step-by-step guide for this. You're basically testing if there is an association between the hotels and the desire to return, and rejecting the null of them being independent is evidence that there is indeed such an association.